# How to toggle keyboard layout in Sway from the shell?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, wayland, sway

How can I toggle between xkb keyboard layouts in Sway from the command line? My layouts are configured like this:

```
input type:keyboard {
    xkb_layout pl,es
    xkb_options grp:win_space_toggle,compose:caps
}
```

I'd like to be able to have a command that switches to the next layout (to `pl` if the current one is `es`, to `es` if the current one is `pl`).

**Note**: There is a command `swaymsg "input type:keyboard xkb_switch_layout <index>"` that allows you to change the layout specifying it's index. I don't know how to use that to toggle to the next one, as I don't know how to get the current index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using sway version 1.5.1, I can provide `next` to `xkb_switch_layout`. So you no longer need to get the current index and number of total items.

```bsh
swaymsg input "1:1:AT_Translated_Set_2_keyboard" xkb_switch_layout next
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use `type:keyboard` instead of the identifier. You can find your identifier with `swaymsg -t get_inputs`. If you want to see all available layouts and the index of the current layout you would need to add `--raw`.

Comment: i have sway 1.8.1 on Fedora 38 and can confirm `type:keyboard` works instead identifed

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the current keyboard layout index of your input by running `swaymsg -t get_inputs`, which will give you a JSON containing an array of inputs and their associated settings.

The keys you are looking for are `xkb_active_layout_index` and `xkb_layout_names`.

Here is an example of the output given by the command on my system (cropped to show the relevant part):

```json
  (...)
  {
    "identifier": "16700:8467:Dell_KB216_Wired_Keyboard",
    "name": "Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard",
    "vendor": 16700,
    "product": 8467,
    "type": "keyboard",
    "xkb_layout_names": [
      "English (US)",
      "Romanian (standard)"
    ],
    "xkb_active_layout_index": 0,
    "xkb_active_layout_name": "English (US)",
    "libinput": {
      "send_events": "enabled"
    }
  },
  (...)
```

To simulate the behavior of sway's toggle, you can use the following code:

```
inputid="YOUR_KEYBOARD_INPUT_IDENTIFIER"

inputdata=$(swaymsg -t get_inputs | jq ".[] | select(.identifier==\"$inputid\")")
index=$(echo "$inputdata" | jq ".xkb_active_layout_index")
layoutcount=$(echo "$inputdata" | jq ".xkb_layout_names | length")
swaymsg input "$inputid" xkb_switch_layout $((($index + 1) % $layoutcount))
```

Using sway version 1.4

Answer (score 0):

You already have the correct configuration. Super+Space should change your keyboard layout (that is what `win_space_toggle` means). There are other key configurations for switching keyboard layouts, you can find them in the man pages: `man 7 xkeyboard-config`.

Comment: Yes, `Win`+`Space` key combination will switch the layout. But I was asking for a command line solution - a command or Bash script that I could execute and would change the layout.